# qt.qpa.fonts: Replace uses of missing font family

Tags: python, pyqt

```
Python 3.9
PyQt6 6.2.3
MacOS Monterey, M1 Air
```

How on earth do I get rid of this message?

I'm creating a project using PyQt6, and I can't seem to get rid of this:

> qt.qpa.fonts: Populating font family aliases took 72 ms. Replace uses
> of missing font family "Menlo" with one that exists to avoid this
> cost.

I've tried explicitly setting the font via QFont:

```
app.setFont(QFont('Helvetica'))
```

And also using Stylesheets (for all elements):

```
app.setStyleSheet("QLabel{font-family: 'Helvetica';}")
```

I also changed the font in VS Code to see if it was my IDE causing it, to no avail.
How do I get rid of this message - or maybe even hide it? 72ms is hardly a performance hit for my application.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems an old bug that has returned after being fixed in previous versions, see https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-87267. That said, it's a warning, it doesn't compromise the program (since you're *not* using that font), and so you can just ignore it.

Comment: @musicamante darn, well at least I'm not going crazy! Thanks for letting me know.